# XCode and Marmalade: Errors on build app

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, marmalade

I have a simple app made in XCode version 6.x and I'm trying to build it with "Marmalade application" for convert to Android platform, but when I click on "Build it" on my XCode (6.x) I view these errors:

[image]

[image]

Anybody know how to solve this? Thanks so much!